# Nullable Reference Types with C# 8

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

Null reference exceptions are one of the top sources of program failures. Tony Hoare called it his billion dollar mistake. So I'm particularly looking forward to C# 8 and the new *nullable reference types* feature. I think I've got a pretty good grasp of the feature and what it's going to mean for my code. There is one aspect I'm struggling the get my head around though and that's how `default` will behave.

Currently in C# `default(string)` will return null. But when C# 8 comes along then doing something like `string x = default(string);` should surely give a compiler warning straight off the bat. Seems like this is a bit of a paradox. I'm also wondering if `default(string?)` will be possible and what would it even return. I guess it would have to be null which just adds to my confusion.

I don't think there has been a preview release of this feature yet, but I was wondering if anyone knows yet how this will be handled.

Comment: There is a [preview](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/wiki/Nullable-Reference-Types-Preview).

Comment: Since `string` will be an object, the `default(string)` giving `null` is pretty much meaningful.

Comment: And [this specific question](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/36#issuecomment-285589701) has been asked and addressed.

Comment: And just in general - C# language design is being done "in the open" over on github. So that's the logical place to search for this kind of information.

Comment: The "billion dollar mistake": I doubt it was a mistake. One time I started watching probably an hour-long video of the guy explaining why it was a mistake. Probably about 20 minutes in, he still hadn't begun giving an explanation, and I didn't spend any more time on it. The problem is not the concept of `null`: that's obviously a very meaningful item, which is conceptually different from values like `""` and `-1`. The problem is that programmers need to learn to do their jobs. If they can't handle the concept of `null`, they probably can't handle much of anything else in programming either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question is possible to answer now, rather than waiting for C# 8 to be released. C# is now developed "in the open", so just ake yourself over to [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQDk4BstWFiAJQkiQDsBjCAFQE8AHFAGgBMQBqAHwAEAmAAgDCAWABQAbzH9p/bgBZ+AMQD2ygBQBKKTMmiZ+2QEYADPwAe/ALz8WJKNhhruJjQG5t0gL5jPQA===), select the `NullabaleReferenceTypes` branch and try the code.

It gives a `warning CS8600: Cannot convert null to non-nullable reference.` as `default` of a reference type is `null` and `null` should not be assigned to the non-nullable `string`.

If you'd prefer to test a preview in VS2017, [a preview plugin is available for the IDE, too](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/wiki/Nullable-Reference-Types-Preview).

Answer (score 0):

I was curious, too.

```
default(string?) // no warning, returns null when nullable reference types are enabled
default(string) // warning CS8603 when nullable reference types are enabled, but it compiles successfully and actually, it returns null, too.
```

That means: In the following scenario, string `a` is not nullable, but it is actually null.

```
string MyMethod(){
    return default;
}
string a = MyMethod();
```

So, if `MyMethod` comes from a foreign library with NullableReferenceTypes enabled, it's still possible that the library developers messed something up and that the method returns null.